# Anonymous access to the master page gallery

Tags: anonymous-authentication

I'm using SharePoint 2013 on prem and have stored some script files under _catalogs/masterpage where the master page that I'm using is stored.

I've enabled anonymous access to the site and the master page folder have also unique permissions to allow anonymous access.

Even so the scripts are not loaded for anonymous users, I'm getting 401 Unauthorized error.

What I'm missing here? Do I need to grant permissions for anonymous users somewhere else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that the script files are checked in, published and approved.